# Could / Should SO become a curator of code projects with good style?

Tags: feature-request

Like many on this list, I'm sometimes called upon to learn new programming languages and keep up with new releases of existing languages.  While documentation and tutorials can help learn the language, it's hard to learn the *idioms* of a language with small isolated examples.

By contrast, when learning how to write idiomatic code, I've found the thing that helps the most is to scrutinize complete large(ish) projects.

But, as far as I know, there's no publicly curated lists of what constitutes clean idiomatic style in larger projects.

With SO's mechanism for community voting, it might make sense to create an SO community dedicated to identifying project that have notably clean idiomatic style.

Note that this would NOT be the same as CodeReview, since the latter answers the question "how can I make my code better?" rather than "where can I find substantial examples of cleanly written code?".

[As an aside: my past feature requests to SO Meta have been roundly downvoted.  I don't expect this time to be much different! :)  If this request doesn't work here, maybe it would be a better fit at github.]

Thoughts?

Comment: Something a bit like Software Recommendations? I wonder if something like this would fit there...

Comment: Definitely not a good fit for Stack Overflow, it's entirely opinion based. Probably not a good fit for Software Recommendations either. Maybe look through http://area51.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm not much of a fan for the idea, either here on Stack Overflow or as a separate site in the network.

Comment: (Cool -- I'm 3 for 3 in negative reputation on SO Meta!  It's my special talent. :))

Answer (score 5):

This would be completely out-of-scope for SO. It also would not likely work very well in an SO/SE-style Q&A, for the following reasons.

- It would be highly opinion-based and subject to endless bickering about spaces before `{` braces, variable naming conventions, and countless other quibbles.
- It would be subject to constant flux as projects change or simply die out and as new coding conventions take hold.
- It would be little more than a coding-style wiki, rather than a Q&A-style site.

There are probably other reasons that this is not a good fit for the network, but these are the big ones that jump out at me.

So, to answer your question,

> Could / Should SO become a curator of code projects with good style?

I would say, "No and no."

Comment: Thanks -- that's a good list of reasons that it should NOT be on SO.  Now, can you think of a constructive answer to "As a competent programmer, how can I find large code projects that my peers believe exemplify clean idiomatic style?"

Comment: @fearless_fool That's going to depend a lot on the language and the technologies involved, and it's going to be largely a matter of opinion; there isn't one answer. As you suggested in your question, though, reviewing the code bases for popular open-source projects is a good place to start. You can also look at projects to which SO participants with high scores in a relevant tag have contributed. But even that is problematic. For example, Wordpress is certainly the most popular PHP project out there, but many people (myself included) hate its coding style.

Comment: Just the mention of 'tabs/spaces' is enough for me to disagree with this proposal.